# Install symfony2 on nginx not load css

Tags: symfony, nginx, symfony-2.3

I have a problem, I want to install symfony2 on nginx, the framework is installed but is not loaded css,js,img. So I view only the home page without style. My installation :

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name symfony.dev;
root /home/vagrant/Workspace/symfony/web;

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/symfony.dev-error.log error;

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

}

I looked in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, there is :

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

And in mime.types exists css,js, etc.
Help me please!
Thnx in advance

Comment: have you installed the assets ?

Comment: No, but normally the css,js, etc would be to load

Comment: try to execute this command : `php app/console assets:install`

Comment: Thnx DOZ.....stupid error

Comment: You're welcome, I'll put the answer for you valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to execute this command to install the assets in web directory :

```
php app/console assets:install
```

Comment: What about bower assets ? This command don't work for this. Thanks.